# Create Dynamic Proxies objects

Tags: wcf, dynamic, proxy

Is there a way to create WCF proxy objects on the fly without using codedom? By on the fly I mean during runtime. So lets say I have a smart client application that is accessing a WCF service. The Data Contract for the WCF service is changed while the client is running. I want to dynamically create a new proxy object that reflects the changed data contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read this article: [WCF the Manual Way… the Right Way](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0809101&page=1)

And look into using the ChannelFactory class. You are going to have alot of reflection to create and invoke the members if the contract changes on the fly but I can't think of any reason you shouldn't be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, using a shared assembly for contracts and endpoint interfaces.

So The Projects Would Be

1. Host
2. Contacts & Endpoints
3. Client With Proxy

   public class YourProxy : ClientBase {}

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about doing too much stuff on the fly.  Even using reflection it might become too easy to couple your Client/Proxy/Service/Contract together too much.

Creating manual proxies and adding them as a reference to your client is a fantastic idea.