# Create proxy without adding service reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web

I work with C# / ASP.NET at Microsoft Web Developer Express 2010.

My Mission is to authenticate and call web service functions (i have all data - web service adress, login/pass, function paremeters).

The only thing i am limited in - i cant use VS2010 add reference funcionality and must do it programmatically. This is necessary because system that uploads my .cs and .aspx files compile them independetly from my project. So my .cs file should include web service function call where i know all paremeters.

I have read some topics about this, but still no result, maybe because people dont work much with systems that compile .cs and .aspx files by themselve.

Comment: Hi Mariya - deffo change the title of your question to something like... create proxy without adding service reference or suchlike. I think someone voted you down - but I've voted you back up (back to zero) as I think you've a valid question but the title isn't clear

Comment: This may help you, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14586/Invoking-a-Web-Service-Without-Web-Reference

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of programmatically creating a WCF client:-

- [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx)

If you can't use WCF at all in the client and the service you are calling is bound basically, you could invoke it using an `HttpWebRequest`:-

- [Invoking WCF service methods without having a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606317/invoking-wcf-service-methods-without-having-a-proxy/6609105#6609105)